# SAS Aligning datasets - using arrays?

Tags: arrays, sas, vertical-alignment

I have a rather complex situation and being new to SAS, I am beating my head against the wall trying to figure out a solution. I have two datasets (controller, daq) and in each dataset there is a measurement of power. I need to align the controller data with the daq data. There is a time stamp in each dataset BUT, they didn't bother time syncing the daq with the controller so there is an indeterminate amount of time delta between the two. To further complicate matters, both systems sample the data at different rates.... and while the controller is only recording data during the test, the daq records for longer periods of time.  So for a typical test run the controller has about 1000 rows of data and the daq has 30,000 rows at different sample rates (which means that the absolute measurements will not likely match exactly).

I am trying to figure out a way to automatically align the data - i.e. figure out where the curve of the controller data most closely matches the curve of the daq data - giving us the time delta.

My current thought is to iterate through two arrays, subtracting daqrow[i] from controllerow[j] and then adding up the delta's for the curve and finding the minimum delta:

```
      set work.daqPower work.controlPower
array pwr_daq{*} daqPwr;  /* daqPwr is name of power variable in work.daqPower */
array pwr_control{*} controlPwr;  /* controllPwr is name of power variable in work.controlPower */
do idaq=1 to (30000 - 1000);
    x = idaq;
    tmp = 0;
    do jcontrol=1 to 1000;
        tmp = tmp + ABS(pwr_daq[x] - pwr_control[jcontrol]);
        x = x + 1;
    end;
    output;
end;
```

I am apparently not understanding the array documentation. I have been searching online and going through a lot of the examples, but what I haven't found are any examples showing reading in two datasets and creating separate arrays from them. I would appreciate any links to similar examples or if you have any ideas for a better approach.

Thanks,

Fred

update w/ data samples:

```
DateTime        daqPower
05JUL12:10:10:00    205.45687866211
05JUL12:10:10:00    204.33529663086
05JUL12:10:10:00    204.17504882813
05JUL12:10:10:00    203.53414916992
05JUL12:10:10:00    203.53414916992
05JUL12:10:10:00    204.81597900391
05JUL12:10:10:00    204.33529663086
05JUL12:10:10:00    205.13641357422
05JUL12:10:10:00    207.05914306641
05JUL12:10:10:00    206.73867797852
05JUL12:10:10:00    207.05914306641
05JUL12:10:10:00    208.50119018555
05JUL12:10:10:00    208.50119018555
05JUL12:10:10:00    207.53982543945
05JUL12:10:10:00    207.21936035156
05JUL12:10:10:00    206.73867797852
05JUL12:10:10:00    206.09777832031
05JUL12:10:10:00    205.77731323242
05JUL12:10:10:00    205.13641357422
05JUL12:10:10:00    205.45687866211

DateTime        controlPower
05JUL12:10:01:19    226.8705902
05JUL12:10:01:19    232.526886
05JUL12:10:01:19    236.9337006
05JUL12:10:01:19    242.3483887
05JUL12:10:01:19    246.9274292
05JUL12:10:01:19    246.3426819
05JUL12:10:01:19    244.3251495
05JUL12:10:01:19    242.6235352
05JUL12:10:01:20    243.5477753
05JUL12:10:01:20    240.9849854
05JUL12:10:01:20    230.8181458
05JUL12:10:01:20    225.579071
05JUL12:10:01:20    221.7199097
05JUL12:10:01:20    214.7053986
05JUL12:10:01:20    212.1452332
05JUL12:10:01:20    210.9714203
05JUL12:10:01:20    213.6631317
05JUL12:10:01:20    213.3510437
05JUL12:10:01:21    209.8970642
05JUL12:10:01:21    210.884964
```

Keep in mind that the times do not match up (we have "heard" that the timestamps may be off sync from each other by approximately 10 minutes+). The point is that the the curve from the controller is a much shorter interval than the daq and we are trying to determine the time difference by aligning where the curve of the controller most closely matches the curve of the controller. I say curve, because initially thought of just matching the max value, but while there is only one max value from the controller data, the daq data goes on for a much longer period and the power curve crosses that value many times, so it would difficult to align the data based on just that.

Comment: You probably do not want to use arrays.  Update your question with some sample data from your two data sets, just enough to illustrate.  And then, show an example of the output data you want.

Comment: Agree with Bob.  SAS doesn't really use Arrays that way - that's more of an R/matrix concept.  Unless you're using IML, SAS prefers to work with rows rather than (column) arrays.  Seems like you should have two datasets, with each value for daq in one row in dataset 1 and each value for controller in dataset 2.  Is that what you have?

Comment: I have updated with data, although, I see that it didn't format properly. Sighhh.  As for the output, ideally, I am looking to identify the timestamp from both daq and control where the curves from daq and control line up the best.  That way we can determine the time offset between the datasets and then automatically adjust them. And yes Joe - your interpretation is correct.  And I could do this fairly quickly in R using it's matrix concept, but we are migrating to SAS and I need to build this up in SAS.

Comment: Hmm.  Seeing that, I'd suggest this might not be an appropriate question for this forum.  This really sounds more like a statistician question than a programmer question.  If I were to try to solve this, I guess I'd go row-by-row, creating a delta for each row, and look at that graphically; but even that is probably not going to be very easy to do programatically.  I assume you can't go to the hardware devices and fix their timestamps? :)

Comment: Fred, do you have SAS/IML licensed?  If so, then you have matrix concept available, which is nearly identical to R in its basics.

Comment: Joe - not at this point. They don't even know for sure what the time delta was between the devices & asked if we can determine it automatically - there are thousands of files that need to be processed & each set of files will likely have a different time delta.  - Fred

Comment: The key is the overall curve for the control dataset should match up fairly closely to a specific portion of the curve of the daq. If we can determine where those line up, then we have our time delta. My thought was to subtract row by row and add up the delta's, then start the process over by incrementing the starting point on the daq by 1, basically shifting the comparison by 1.  And then looking at where the sum of delta's is the lowest. That "should (I am hoping :) )" give me the two timestamps where they line up and I can determine the delta. - Fred

Comment: I'd wonder if you can fit this using a regression model of some sort.  Create one curve, and then see if you can get the other to fit the curve.  That's well out of my area of expertise, unfortunately, so I can't help there.

Comment: Is your example correct?  In other words, do they really all the same timestamp?  What makes one row different from another?  This might be "solved" with a simple `merge`, but I must be missing something.

Comment: Bob, no they don't have exactly the same timestamp. The field just shows down to the second. The daq dataset is sampled at 50Hz, so 50 samples per second, I should have expanded the format to show milliseconds.

Comment: Is the power in control data, the min, max, average, first(opening), last(closing) power for that period in time?  You may be able to look at the opening and closing time for each period in the control, and focus on finding a time interval where every (or the majority of...) observation in the more frequently sampled dataset falls between the opening and closing intervals. To narrow it down, find either the max or min in the control, and try and align those first as they should probably require the max/min observations from the other dataset as well.

Answer (score 0):

Fred, here are a few ideas that you could try.  I agree that IML might be the way for you to go, but you've got to use what you've got on hand.

First, using arrays you can modify your controller dataset using either PROC TRANSPOSE or a DATA step with a RETAIN statement to make two arrays (one for time, the other for measurement) and output only the final observation after the all of the array elements have been filled. You can then use a separate DATA step with two SET statements (the first to set the DAQ dataset, followed by "IF *N* EQ 1 THEN SET <1 observation POWER dataset name>;".  You would need to set up arrays in this new dataset and use the RETAIN statement again to keep them throughout the processing.  You can then use DO loops to process the information in the array where the time variable in the DAQ observation is equal to or between the dates of the POWER observation that is stored in the time array.  This is a rather messy way to process the information and will result in a rather large matrix, unless you use a KEEP or DROP statement to limit the final output.  However, this method would allow you to modify the CONTROLLER observation by some extrapolated value between multiple observations.

In contrast, I don't think my second and third suggestions will allow you to extrapolate between two values, but I'll suggest them anyway.

Second option, use PROC FORMAT to create a user-defined format from the CONTROLLER dataset with the value being the time and the formatted value being the POWER observation.  You would need to have the data sorted by time and then you could use the lag function to define the START and END values to pass into the format.  After the format is created you can then use the format to create a new variable within your DAQ dataset based on where the DAQ-time variable's formatted value.  As mentioned above, it would not be feasible to extrapolate between values using this process.

The third option is a variation of the second one, but instead of using a format you can use a DATA Step Component Object to create a hash object that you can iterate through to retrieve the value that you need.  I don't use this method often so I won't bother trying to describe it, but you can find documentation on the SAS site for it.

There's a fourth option that might be even better than any of these, but you would have to have the SAS/ETS module to use it.  You might be able to use the EXPAND procedure to extrapolate the POWER observations in your CONTROL data set to a time frequency that is consistent with your DAQ dataset time variable, then merge this expanded data set with the DAQ dataset.  This method would give you quite a bit of control on how the extrapolation is done and would fairly easy to implement, but once again, you have to have the ETS module to use that procedure.

I haven't provided any examples because of the excess wordiness of my answer (would have been a comment but got too long), but let me know if you want me to try to provide some sample code for one of the methods discussed.  Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. While googling last night, I did find the PROC EXPAND function and it turns out that we have both IML and ETS.  It looks like the EXPAND function might solve the problem the easiest. I'll post once I have dug into it and figured out the right approach

Answer (score 0):

Since you have ETS, see this example for PROC TIMESERIES, especially the cross-correlation plots at the end:

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/63348/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_timeseries_sect044.htm

The cross-correlation plot will peak at the optimal lag.

You can also use PROC TIMESERIES to normalize the sampling rates.